# ConEmu: possible to change the up arrow behavior?

Tags: conemu

The <kbd>↑</kbd> arrow cycles through the command history, for example, I get these suggestions:

```
cd project
git init
git commit
cd ..
```

Is it possible to adjust the behavior of the up arrow in ConEmu so that it behaves like in zsh which filters the suggestions based on my current prompt? For example, if I wrote "git" to the console, up arrow would only cycle through these two:

```
git init
git commit
```

Comment: What restricts you from running zsh in ConEmu??? You question looks like: "I want formatting tools in Notepad, like WinWord provides"...

Comment: I want this single feature from zsh, not the full shell, if possible.

Comment: I have this exact same question. Have you found an answer? The closest I have been able to get is to use Ctrl+R, but I would prefer to not have to do that.

Comment: @Phil I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by installing clink: http://mridgers.github.io/clink/ and enabling it in the settings (see docs: https://conemu.github.io/en/TabCompletion.html)

Comment: Note that https://github.com/chrisant996/clink is the maintained fork of clink.