# ConEmu + zsh: how will keyboard shortcuts and other shell features work?

Tags: zsh, git-bash, conemu

I'm trying to wrap my head around this: on Windows, I use [cmder](http://cmder.net/) (a wrapper around [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/)) which improves on the bare `cmd.exe` experience (a *lot*) but can also host other shells like PowerShell or Git Bash. I'd like to go more "unix-y" but still well integrated with my Windows tools. Git Bash strikes the right balance for me: I can do things like `rm -rf node_modules` but still run my Windows commands fine.

It's easy to get Git Bash going inside cmder, however, I'd like to replace the shell with **zhs**, mainly to get the super-useful "up arrow respects the current prefix" feature (I write `git`, press the up arrow and only get suggestions on the recent Git commands).

The question is, who will handle the up arrow? Will it be ConEmu and do Windows-y stuff (cycling through all the commands) or will it fall down to zsh and the cycling will be implemented by it? How does this work?

Related: [ConEmu: possible to change the up arrow behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40782444/conemu-possible-to-change-the-up-arrow-behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ConEmu's disclaimer](https://conemu.github.io/en/#Disclaimer) states

> ConEmu is not a shell, so it does not provide "shell features" like remote access, tab-completion, command history and others.

Only the shell itself knows when user types a command and only the shell may store executed commands history. Of course, only the shell may process Up/Down/Tab keys to "browse" stored history of commands.

cmder is a bundle of tools including clink, which integrates into cmd.exe and process cmd's prompt internally. So, in cmder by default Up/Down/Tab arrows are processed by clink.

More info is here: http://conemu.github.io/en/TabCompletion.html

Comment: Great explanation, I didn't realize the role of clink and its relation to cmd.exe (and cmd.exe only). Thanks!